# What is the pythonic way of doing nothing?

Tags: python

I need my main program, at some point, to do nothing - forever (there are threads started earlier which do some work).

I was wondering what was the pythonic way to do so. I particularly would like to avoid losing CPU cycles on this nothingness.

My immediate guess was `time.sleep(100000)` where `100000` is large enough for the life of my program. It works but is not aesthetically pleasant. I checked the CPU load of a python session running this: not measurable (close to zero).

I also tried

```
while True:
    pass
```

It looks nicer but the hit on the CPU is enormous (~25%).

Is there [one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)?

Comment: Please notice that you still need to use `while True: …` for `time.sleep()`, because signals (such as a terminated child) [can break the timeout](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.sleep) (fixed in 3.5).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would like to wait for the thread to exit, use [`thread.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.join):

> `join([timeout])`
>
> Wait until the thread terminates. This blocks the
>   calling thread until the thread whose join() method is called
>   terminates – either normally or through an unhandled exception – or
>   until the optional timeout occurs.

Example usage:

```
import threading
t = threading.Thread(name='non-daemon', target=non_daemon)

t.start() # This will not block
t.join() #  This is blocking
```